# GiltLab CI/CD Django tests failing

Tags: django, testing, gitlab, continuous-integration

I want to run some tests on Gitlab with CI/CD with a Django project. The tests on my local pc work fine, my job test pipeline is always failing with those tests. I get a SyntaxError.

Here the script failure I get in the pipeline when the tests failed :

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.3.0~beta.42.gdb7789ca (db7789ca)
  on blue-3.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default zxwgkjAP
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:06
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.5 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.5 ...
Using docker image sha256:27d049ce98db4e55ddfaec6cd98c7c9cfd195bc7e994493776959db33522383b for ruby:2.5 with digest ruby@sha256:ecc3e4f5da13d881a415c9692bb52d2b85b090f38f4ad99ae94f932b3598444b ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-zxwgkjap-project-39068925-concurrent-0 via runner-zxwgkjap-shared-1662191947-427cb239...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/XXX/Deploy_django_application_to_server/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 51c8456f as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
Using docker image sha256:27d049ce98db4e55ddfaec6cd98c7c9cfd195bc7e994493776959db33522383b for ruby:2.5 with digest ruby@sha256:ecc3e4f5da13d881a415c9692bb52d2b85b090f38f4ad99ae94f932b3598444b ...
$ echo "Running unit tests..."
Running unit tests...
$ python manage.py test app_users.tests.CustomUserTests
  File "manage.py", line 17
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

*the script of my .gitlab-ci.yml is :

```yaml
    stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
      - build
      - test
      - deploy
    
    build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
      stage: build
      script:
        - echo "Compiling the code..."
        - apt update
        - echo y | apt install python3-pip
        - pip3 install --upgrade pip
        - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    
    django-tests:
      stage: test
      script:
        - echo "Running unit tests..."
        - python manage.py test app_users.tests.CustomUserTests
        - python manage.py test app_manage.tests.BasePageTestCase
        - python manage.py test app_manage.tests.TermesPageTestCase
        - python manage.py test app_manage.tests.IndexTestCase
        - python manage.py test app_manage.tests.SearchTestCase
    
    lint-test-job:   # This job also runs in the test stage.
      stage: test    # It can run at the same time as unit-test-job (in parallel).
      script:
        - echo "Linting code... This will take about 10 seconds."
        - echo "No lint issues found."
```

*I understand it comes from my manage.py file line 17 but I this is the default setting of manage.py. I pushed my Django project from my Pycharm IDE directly to GitLab. I have a Postgresql database for this project. I use TestCase and SimpleTestCase in my Django project.

I'm stuck in GitLab CI /CD with my tests job:-(. thanks!

Comment: Could you provide us with the python version you have in your dev environment, the python version in your production environment and your django version ?

Comment: The python version im my dev environment : 3.8
The python version in the production environment : seems to be 3.7 in the build job
the django version : 3.2.3

Comment: I think you are in python2 on your docker environment. See my response below.

Answer (score 0):

Your docker image uses python2.7 as `python` executable. I got this information by doing the following:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --entrypoint bash ruby:2.5
root@c4cf25791396:/# python --version
Python 2.7.16
root@c4cf25791396:/# python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

Django is not compatible with python2.7 (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django).

You should either use a docker image using python3 as default python interpreter, or directly call the `python3` executable.

```yaml
    django-tests:
      stage: test
      script:
        - echo "Running unit tests..."
        - python3 manage.py test app_users.tests.CustomUserTests
        - python3 manage.py test app_manage.tests.BasePageTestCase
```